# updating mysql after set time has passed

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie to the php and mysql.. I have been trying to update my mysql automatically after the set time has passed ..With my program I needs to check the time with the current time everyday and if the time passes then it should update my database. Is there a way to do this using mysql and php ?.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need some mechanism to check time has passed `cron` for example. With `cron` you can run your script daily for example

Comment: Hint, you can call a PHP script from cron, using a command line like `php myscript.php`.

Comment: Thanks .. It seems like I need to learn about the cron... any good tutorial you know which talks about the cron tab... and how to use it with my php